# Java List reference another List to modify itself

Tags: java, algorithm

I feel like there most likely is a java library function to do this, and possibly another question on StackOverflow similar to this, but I couldn't find anything in my preliminary search.

I have two `java.util.List` objects, `ListA` and `ListB`. I want to use `ListB`, which is larger than `ListA`, to modify my elements in `ListA`. In order to do this, I need to match an ID from `ListA` to its corresponding element in `ListB` (my prior code ensures that every element in `ListA` will be in `ListB`) and then use a field in `ListB` to modify `ListA`.

Is a Hash function the best way to do this? or is there a better way?

EDIT: The two lists don't have the same type of objects

Comment: If the lists contain same type of object, you could implement `hashCode` and `equals` on that object using the `id` field, and use `indexOf` to find A objects in the list.

Comment: a map with ID <-> object is your way to go. Convert your ListB to a map. Then you can use the ID to get the corresponding object to modify ListA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably create a `Map` from `ListB`, mapping the ID attribute to the element from `ListB` that correspond to that ID. Even if `ListB` being a list is a given, it is probably faster to convert it to a `Map` on the fly than to search the entire `ListB` for each element in `ListA`.

You can then just get the corresponding `B` for any `A` and modify that `A` accordingly. Here's a simplified example.

```
class A { int id; String foo; }
class B { int id; String bar; }

List<A> listA = ...
List<B> listB = ...
Map<Integer, B> mapB = listB.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(b -> b.id, b -> b));
for (A a : listA) {
    B b = mapB.get(a.id);
    a.foo = b.bar;
}
```

Comment: I did something similar to this but used a MultiMap instead and populated with a for loop, only because the people I'm collaborating with prefer MultiMaps. I think in general this is the best answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `HashSet` might be your best bet. When you add a new element to a `HashSet`, a hashing algorithm gives a key to every unique element. If you're checking IDs, a `Hash` key might be your answer. Also, your prior code that guarantees might become obsolete, as `HashSet` will add every element from `ListA` to `ListB` if you want it to. I would like to give you more specific advice, but your question is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: depends.

The optimal data structure to use depends on your exact requirements. When your **main** (almost only) use case is to fetch an object from list B based on an entry in list A - then the natural choice would be a `Map<ID, ListBEntry>`. That could meant you actually don't have a list B in the end; just that map.

But in case their are other usage patterns, you might have to keep a map and both lists around.

Or, if your constraint is **memory** (not CPU cycles/performance), you might even just go with two lists and **search** lists for matching values each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think [tobias_k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45084925/1876620) is absolutely correct. Here I'd like to show a different way of coding his solution:

```
Map<ID, B> map = new HashMap<>();
listB.forEach(b -> map.put(b.getID(), b));

listA.replaceAll(a -> {
    B b = map.get(a.getID());
    // modify a with b here
    return a;
});
```